# Write JSON to file in python iteratively

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a large JSON response I'm reading from an HTTP request. Is there any easy way in Python to write JSON to file iteratively so that I don't have to read the entire JSON response into memory? With CSV and other data types its much simpler bc you can just append the file but the closing brackets/commas in JSON obviously make it a bit trickier

Apologies if this has already been asked

Comment: Did you look into json streamers?

Comment: the response you've received is already in memory so there is no point in writing it iteratively.

Comment: The API I'm calling pages large results so writing iteratively is very much significant. @Notrius I have no, any particular points there?